# Web scraping with python from online dictionary(reverso context)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to create a program that searches for an inputted list of words in german and finds them in Reverso Context with the appropriate examples of these words. After finding them, the inputted words will be deleted and the examples will be represented without these words. I tried doing these but for one word:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

inp = input("Type a german word\n")

web = requests.get('https://context.reverso.net/translation/german-english/'+inp)

data = web.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, features = "html.parser")

tag = soup.find_all("span","text","de")

a = 1
for i in tag:
    print(a, ".", i.text)
    a = a+1
```

help to suit for requirements I wrote, please.

Answer (score 0):

Every iterateion you can see this message `Please enter the word to collect the data or you want to end the prosecc, enter the charcter 'e':` or you can make `list of word` and itertae it you got the same result.You can try it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers =  {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT x.y; Win64; x64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0 '}

mark = ""

while mark != 'e':
    inp = input("Please enter the word to collect the data or you want to end the prosecc, enter the charcter 'e': ")
    mark = inp
    if mark == 'e':
        break
    s = requests.Session()
    url = f'https://context.reverso.net/translation/german-english/{inp}'
    web = s.get(url,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(web.text,"lxml")

    tag = soup.select("span",class_="text",lang="de")

    a = 1
    for i in tag:
        if ('\n' or "") in i.text :
           print(a, ". ",  i.text.strip())
           a = a+1
    # print("Do You have any List of word?")
    print("."*80)
```

Output will be:

```
1 .  Join Reverso
2 .  
3 .  Facebook connect
4 .  Google connect
5 .  Zeigt die Anzahl der heute blockierten Ereignisse an.
6 .  Displays the number of events that have been blocked today.
7 .  In diesem Sinne werden wir heute die Entlastung verweigern.
8 .  It is for this reason that we are today refusing to grant discharge.
9 .  Die Agrarerzeugnisse sind heute ein wesentlicher Bestandteil der Verhandlungsrunden der Welthandelsorganisation.
10 .  Agricultural products are now an integral part of the World Trade Organisation negotiating round.
11 .  Das ist heute die wichtigste Frage.
12 .  This is the pressing issue we now face.
13 .  Sie wird in vergleichbaren Fällen heute anders vorgehen.
14 .  It would take a different approach in comparable cases today.
15 .  Kutschma regiert heute als allmächtiger Präsident.
16 .  Today, Kuchma rules as an all-powerful president.
17 .  Für mich verbleibt heute nur eine wesentliche Frage.
18 .  In my view, there is only one important question left today.
19 .  Die heute diskutierte Verordnung wird unsere Aktion fraglos verbessern helfen.
20 .  The regulation we are debating today will undoubtedly contribute to improving our action.


and so on......
```

You can also try it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers =  {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT x.y; Win64; x64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0 '}

mark = ""

while mark != 'e':
    inp = input("Please enter the word to collect the data or you want to end the prosecc, enter the charcter 'e': ")
    mark = inp
    if mark == 'e':
        break
    s = requests.Session()
    url = f'https://context.reverso.net/translation/german-english/{inp}'
    web = s.get(url,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(web.text,"lxml")

    # tag = soup.select("span",class_="text",lang="de")

    sentences = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.find_all('span', {'class':'text'},{"lang" : "de"}) if '\n' in x.text]
    print(sentences)
    print("."*80)
```

You get the same result as list.

Comment: @Sanzhik If you use windows, don't need to change it.

Comment: @Sanzhik, Glad to help out, please consider to upvote and/or accept if it helped. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a python wrapper for Reverso Context API: https://github.com/flagist0/reverso_context_api

In your case, you can use it like this:

```
from itertools import islice
from reverso_context_api import Client

def get_samples(client, word, num=5):
    # There can be thousands of translation samples, this function requests and returns only needed amount of them
    iterator = client.get_translation_samples(word)
    return list(islice(iterator, num))

client = Client(source_lang="de", target_lang="en")
# call get_samples for each word in your list
print(get_samples(client, "Fortschritt"))

# Outputs:
# [('Überprüfen Sie den Fortschritt des Datenbank-Loaders im Prozessmanager.',
#   'Check the progress of the Database Loader in your Process Manager.'),
#  ('Status verfolgen auch den Fortschritt des Auftragsabschlussprozesses.',
#   'Statuses also track the progress of the job close process.'),
#  ('Kommissar Vitorino hatte das Abkommen als großen Fortschritt bezeichnet.',
#   "Commissioner Vitorino has described it as a 'major advance'."),
#  ('Dies ist deshalb schon ein großer Fortschritt.',
#   'This is, therefore, already a major advance.'),
#  ('Ich betrachte die Charta als akzeptablen Fortschritt.',
#   'I consider that the Charter of Fundamental Rights represents a valuable step forward.')]
```